# Python - Constructing a subprocess.popen with redirection

Tags: python, arguments, redirect, subprocess

I want to create a subprocess with popen.
The special demand is to use shell direction in the command.

```
args = [
    '/bin/cat',
    '<',
    'textfile',
    ]
process = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                           env={'LANG':'de_DE@euro'})
processpid = process.pid
output = process.communicate()
```

I do not want to use the shell=True option, therefore here my question to you, how to implent it.

Regards
Stefan

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Impossible unless the program you're calling implements redirection itself (which `cat` doesn't). To use shell features, you have to pass `shell=True` or invoke a shell explicitly.

OTOH, if you just want to read from `textfile`, you could pass it as the subprocess's `stdin`:

```
subprocess.Popen(args,
                 stdin=open("textfile"),
                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                 stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                 env={'LANG':'de_DE@euro'})
```